# Beginner question: Using Python/Anaconda; Can't find '_main_' module in script

Tags: python, shell, module, scripting, anaconda

I'm currently doing the Udacity tutorial for Python scripting. The first step is to run a simple script that says "Congratulations on running this script!!".

I did this before in the past. Now I'm revisiting python but I'm getting the error: Can't find '*main*' module in first-script.py.

I'm a beginner. Here's what I've tried:

1. Uninstall and reinstall the latest versions of: Python, Git Bash, and Anaconda.
2. I've made sure to cd my way to the correct directory
3. I've made sure to unzip the file
4. I've triple and quadruple checks that I've typed everything correctly. I typed python first-script.py

The first time I did this it was easy. Now I'm running into this problem. I'm doing this through the Anaconda terminal. I downloaded Python 3.9, typing python3 first-script.py gives the error "python3" isn't recognized, so I know it's correct to type in the former style despite the version being python 3.

I think the problem might have something to do with "PATH", but I don't fully understand what that is.

Back in the first time I did this I configured Git Bash to run Python and Anaconda thought I realize now I didn't need to do that, and that it was optional (I think?)

I'm sorry for such as basic question, but I'm really lost. There must be something I changed.

HERE IS MY CODE WITH ERROR MESSAGE BELOW

(base) C:\Users\my name>cd Desktop                                                                                                                                                                                                    (base) C:\Users\my name\Desktop>cd Scripting                                                                                                                                                                                          (base) C:\Users\my name\Desktop\Scripting>python first-script.py                                              C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe: can't find '**main**' module in 'first-script.py'                                                                                                                                                          (base) C:\Users\my name\Desktop\Scripting>

EDIT: Some people are saying the issue is involved with PATH. My OS is Windows 10

**SOLUTION**: Guys, I just discovered what I did wrong. I was in the WRONG directory!! All my scripts go into my "Python" folder. However, the tutorial script I downloaded is held WITHIN a folder. The FOLDER is called "first-script.py", BUT THE SCRIPT ITSELF IS CALLED "first_script.py". I had to first do "cd first-script.py", and then execute the script "python first_script.py. Pretty silly, and such a small thing to overlook.

Comment: "Can't find 'main' module in first-script.py." Huh? Can you post the full error message including the stack trace?

Comment: Can you show your code? Also please make sure that your file is saved as `.py`.

Comment: (base) C:\Users\Gianluca Bannwart\Desktop\Scripting>python first-script.py                                              C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in 'first-script.py'                                                                                                                                                          (base) C:\Users\Gianluca Bannwart\Desktop\Scripting>

Comment: Thanks for providing the error message in your comment.  It is best to [edit] your question and add the error message there, so people can see it right away.  See the "help" link while editing to see how to format the error message as code.

Answer (score 0):

For the python error, you have to use `py -3.9` instead of `python3` because you're on windows. Regarding the main thing, I would assume you tried to import something that doesn't exist. Please put your code because that is extremely weird. The only code you should need for that is

```
print("Congratulations on running this script!!")
```

. If you have anything else please update your question with your full code

Comment: I've edited my original post with the code, to execute the script I use simply "python" followed by "first-script.py"

Comment: To run the script you would have to type `py -3.9 first-script.py`. By code, I mean the contents of the actual python file.

Comment: Hey @snakebite-382 I re-opened Git Bash and saw a prompt at the very top.

bash: /c/Users/My Name/anaconda3/Scripts/conda.exe: No such file or directory

Maybe this error might have something to do with the situation? 

As for reading the code in the actual python file, every time I click on it a box appears and quicky disappears. Clicking doesn't open it. Could that be the problem?

Comment: @Gianluca It appears an Anaconda environment hasn't been set up properly or you aren't in the correct directory. To open the script you have to open it with a text editor like notepad,notepad++, Sublime Text, VScode, whatever you want to use. Double-clicking on a python file will attempt to open it so unless you have an application with a GUI nothing will happen.

Comment: Hey @snakebite-382 you were right! I was in the wrong directory! That's because the script I downloaded was in a folder. The FOLDER is called "first-script.py", and the script is called "first_script.py". I had to "cd first-script.py" to get to the right directory and THEN execute the script. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

When you download the script from Udacity, it is in the form of a zip file named first-script.py.zip. You have to extract the python script from that zip file which when extracted, will be first_script.py. Then you should run this extracted script. This worked for me at least.